# Check for uninitialized array in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to check if array is initialized in Swift. I am working on iOS Programming Big Nerd Ranch Guide, the code is in objective C and I am trying to write that in swift. I need a way to check if the array in initialized or not please check the below code:

```
var items1:[string]  
var items2:[string]!

override init(){
    super.init()
    //how do i check if items1 or items2 is initialized 
    if(items1 == nil){ //this does not work
    //Initialize the array and do something with it!! 
    }
}
```

Comment: have a look in the kink above it may help you a lot with your question

Answer (score 1):

If you have a property with `?`(items1)or`!`(items2),you need to check if it is initialized or not.Because it can be nil

You do not check `items3`,because it have to be initialized in `init` method.

```
class TestClass:NSObject{
    var items1:[String]?;
    var items2:[String]!
    var items3:[String]

    override init() {
        items3 = [String]()
        super.init()
    }

    func testFunction(){
        if items1 == nil{

        }
        if items2 == nil{

        }
    }
}
```

You can check if an Array is empty with this

```
if items3.count == 0{

}
```

Or this

```
if items3.isEmpty{

}
```

Comment: The key point is that if you have a var or let that isn't optional, the compiler requires that you assign it a value in your initializer(s). If you don't your code won't compile.

Comment: That is the whole point of optional and required variables in swift. If it isn't optional, it can **never** be nil once the init method has executed. You can depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .isEmpty method to check for items.
With the if let statement check if an object is initialized.

```
let array = Books(title: "Title")


if let newBook = array {
    println("A book was initialized with the title \(array.title)")
}
```